# convert NSAttributedstring (with NSTextAttachment having image) to html in ios obj c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I know how to convert the common `NSAttributedString` (which has no image) into HTML. I set the Images as `NSTextAttachment` to `NSAttributedString`. How could I convert the whole attributed string into HTML?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = image;
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString    alloc] initWithString:htmlString];

NSAttributedString *attstringImage = [NSAttributedString  attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

[attributedString appendAttributedString:attstringImage];

NSAttributedString *titleContent = (NSAttributedString *)attributedString;

NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:  NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
NSData *htmlData = [titleContent dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, titleContent.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];

NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Please suggest me with quick answer

Comment: Does it appear in the `html` string at the end? I mean, does "html" has some "<img src="">?

Comment: it has  no <img src="">?

Comment: I tested with putting `<img src="anImageURL">` inside `htmlString`, and converting it into NSAttributedString worked, but the reverse operation simply committed the image. So I guess that you would have to add yourself (no easy) the html tags for the image.

Comment: you implement that?.I fetch same issue.